# UIRouter - Dynamically change ui-view attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to dynamically change the ui-view attribute such as each time the attribute changes, the view changes too...

I use multiple views as follow:

```
$stateProvider.state('main',
        {url: "/main",
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: "partials/main", controller: "MainCtrl" },
                'clients@main': {templateUrl: "partials/client-list", controller: "ClientListCtrl"},
                'impexp@main': {templateUrl: "partials/imp-exp", controller: "ImpExpCtrl"}
            }
        }
    );
```

In my MainCtrl I define a $scope variable as follow:

```
$scope.main_view = 'clients';
```

and my HTML/jade:

```
div(ng-attr-ui-view='{{ main_view }}'
```

The problem is that when I change dynamically $scope.main_view, my view doesn't change.

Is it possible to dynamically change a ui-view? if it is, how?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Instead of using an attribute, why not use the built-in states?

Comment: I have multiple views where only one needs to change and I don't want to reload the whole page...If you have a better solution, I'm open

Comment: Changing states doesn't reload the whole page, it inputs the template into the ui-view div.

Comment: how can I change the state from the main view?

Comment: You can do it on an event. Either through <a ui-sref="state"> or passing in state to your controller, $state.go('state'), check out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**StateProvider** (possibly app.js)

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: "/main",
      templateUrl: "partials/main.html",
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('main.substate', {
      url: "/", // Inherits /main from parent state
      templateUrl: "partials/client-list.html",
      controller: 'ClientListCtrl',
    });
```

Any template will be loaded into `<div ui-view>`

**HTML Example:**

```
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div ng-include="'../views/main-nav.html'" ng-controller="NavCtrl"></div>

<div id="main" ui-view=""></div><!-- end #main -->

<div ng-include="'../views/footer.html'"></div>
```

**Events to trigger state change:**

```
<a ui-sref="main.substate">Changes out template and controller</a>

<span ng-click="$state.go('main.substate')">Clicking this will change template</span>
```

Checkout the ui-router [$state docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Comment: I'm missing something... the div(ui-view) will open main but what will open client-list for default view? And how can I manage the position and size of my nested client-list view?

Comment: client-list will load in the spot that main loaded in, if you want to set client-list as default view, you'll need to handle that in your stateProvider. You'd style your templates the same way, add a container in client-list.html with a selector and you're good to go.

Comment: Added a layout example with header/footer partials.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that my ui-view shows only my main.html... client-list.html should be nested into my main right?

Comment: In this setup, your client-list would take the spot of your main.html. If you want main.html to have client-list inside of that, You can use an ng-include with a ng-show bound to your model.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to avoid... I thought ui-router was used for nested views and multiple views. Anyway, I think includes and ng-show will do the job

Comment: I think I misunderstood your goal. :\